# Cannot use tables which have only primary key

Tags: sql, model-view-controller, models

I used a database first approach whereby I created the models from the database tables.

I have the following 3 tables:

```
CategoryTypeSex
ProductColor
ProductCategory
```

These are the only 3 tables that consist of only 2 fields (whereby both fields are primary keys and have a relation with other tables)

[image: snippet1]

The screenshot above shows the diagram definition generated by mvc where the last 3 tables represent the tables mentioned above.

How can tables having only 2 fields which are both primary keys be accessed from the model?

Comment: your screenshot is not uploaded